# Math reviews in "Zentralblatt für Mathematik und ihre Grenzgebiete"

Tags: reference-request, zbmath

Is there a website where i could read/download math reviews appeared in the above Journal?

Of course, I guess all the reviews are available on ZBMATH https://zbmath.org/, which is not free for access. Besides, the reviews (before 1990s) on ZBMATH are uploaded as scanned files, not very clear and non-searchable.

Comment: Sorry, zbMATH is free. There are some restrictions for  users (see https://zbmath.org/terms-conditions/).

Comment: @user64494 "Free access is limited to 3 results, and filter functions are disabled. For full access subscription is required."

Comment: I see a certain contradiction between having it freely available without restrictions and improving the quality.

Comment: It's indeed not free. Good news, it should be [free from 2021 on](https://www.fiz-karlsruhe.de/en/nachricht/zbmath-open-informationen-fuer-die-mathematik-werden-frei-zugaenglich)

Answer (score 8):

1. The site you mention is partially free. Without the subscription it gives you a reduced version. Basically, the reduction consists in giving you only 3 first items
   on any search you try to make. If you state your search parameters smartly, you can extract a lot of information using this reduced version. It also gives you author's profiles.
2. Those reviews that they have in TeX are available in pdf. Those which were written
   before the spread of TeX are simply scanned. Your complain that they are poorly legible seems strange: how would you imagine old printed texts are converted to electronic formats? Only by scanning. Or do you think someone will hire great armies
   of qualified people to put them in TeX, and then distribute them for free?

Comment: @ Alexandre Eremenko: If the database is sold as "a product", then they could surely improve its quality, say, using more clear files. Some reviews are written by true experts and hence useful to other math workers. Simply uploading non-searchable scanned files greatly reduced its function.

Comment: @student: the ZblMath database is indeed a very useful product. And it was useful also 20 years ago when it existed on paper only, when the only "search feature" was a paper index. Converting old mathematical literature into searchable files will not justify expenses.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko it is understandable that ZB simply scanned old stuff, but it is not inconceivable to retype old reviews in LaTeX. For example, MathSciNet has all of its past reviews back to 1940 in TeX format. I don't know if they hired "great armies" to accomplish that task, but obviously it was a substantial investment of time and resources. And ZB is less than 10 years older than Math Reviews. Maybe Ed Dunne will see this post and comment on the different approaches taken by MR and ZB to making old reviews electronically accessible (at least for those with subscriptions).

Comment: "non-searchable" is a solved problem, though it is annoyingly hard to apply in practice (there are OCR libraries around, but no "one-click" solutions to my knowledge).

Comment: @KConrad MathSciNet is subscription only, and the cost of a subscription is more than \$10,000. Aside from that one service, AMS has around 30,000 members with annual typical membership fees over $100. An organization with a multi-million-dollar annual budget *can* afford to "hire an army" if it feels so inclined. The European Mathematical Society (one of the sponsors of ZBMATH) has one-tenth as many members as AMS, and much smaller subscription fees.

Comment: @ darij grinberg: Due to the low quality of the scanned file, OCR will produce lots of mistakes (and this brings trouble if you were using google translation). BTW, it will not cost too much if ZBMATH could at least make the "reviewer's name" searchable.

Comment: I suppose everyone agrees that math papers are more important than their reviews. Can you give me a single math journal of pre-TeX era, which has been re-typed in TeX? All we have on Internet are scanneed copies, some are better, others worse. Even for books re-typing is extremelly rare.